# java design patterns for instance reuse

Tags: java

What are some common design patterns to reuse instances? I have been sticking new instances in a static instance Map in the factory method to achieve this. Are there more elegant/effective/native/convenient design patterns out there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like an [object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). See also [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/).

Comment: what is an instance map in a factory? Can you explain with code what you're looking for and why your solution seems bad / what your doubts are?

Comment: Thanks Elliot. Zapl, I meant a static member of the type Map that has a key (like Id) of the instance, and the value as the instance itself.

Comment: This sounds like the flyweight pattern. You have to be more specific when you say "reusable", as the flyweight pattern is a great pattern for re-using immutable objects. Seems like you are already using a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8, looking up or creating a shared instance using .computeIfAbsent(key, this::instanceCreatingMethod) on a static ConcurrentHashMap is fast, thread-safe, and simple.

Making your instance cache *static*, though, makes it a global variable.  Be sure you're not making a design mistake.

Comment: `static` does not make it global, as it could still be marked `private`

Comment: it's still a global variable, because there will be public methods that change it and access it.   You have to be careful to with this kind of cache to ensure that all the instances you're caching are thread-safe objects that won't let threads interfere with each other.